# Angular 6 service Post request giving error(404) with number argument

Tags: angular, typescript, post, asp.net-web-api, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and new to it. Trying to get Data through POST request from Web API but failed and getting 404 error on service URL. The service is working with GET and POST request without this `number` argument and I think, that `UserId` as an argument is creating problem for me.

Service.ts

```
  getHistory(UserId: number): Observable<History> {
    return this.http.post<History>('/api/getUserHistory', UserId);
  }
```

XYZ.component.ts

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.connectService.getHistory(8).subscribe(fi => {
      console.log(fi);
    });
  }
```

ASP.NET Web API

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/seller_get_userHistory")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetHistory(int UserId)
    {
        try
```

Comment: Are you sure the backend API route is set up correctly to take an argument?

Comment: Yes, I think so...updated my question.

Comment: although 404 means the API is not found, can you try mapping your response before subscribing to it?

Comment: But, it is working while POST and GET without that number argument.

Comment: Does your route attribute need to be like `[Route("api/seller_get_userHistory/{UserId}")]`?

Comment: I'm assuming you have the correct endpoint in the Service.ts file right?
this is not right '/api/getUserHistory'.
It should be http://localhost... blah .../api/getUserHistory

Answer (score 1):

Your service file should have the correct endpoint.

Service.ts

```
  getHistory(UserId: number): Observable<History> {
    return this.http.post<History>('/api/getUserHistory', UserId);
  }
```

To

```
  getHistory(UserId: number): Observable<History> {
    return this.http.post<History>('http://yourHost/api/getUserHistory', UserId);
  }
```